How to Prevent Model Compatibility Check using MySQL Membership Provider for ASP.NET MVC
I have production app that used Kim Ki Won's ASP.NET MVC 4 membership provider (https://github.com/xyz37/MySqlSimpleMembershipProvider). I tried to upgrade it using zijianhuang's fork at (https://github.com/zijianhuang/mysqlmembershipprovider). However I keep getting error
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata.
Yes my db (MYSQL) does not have __migrations table and also metadata. I tried every suggestions provided at (Entity Framework 6.1.1 disable model compatibility checking) to turn off model compatibility check still I keep getting the error.
How to do upgrade my app without model compatibility check? Any suggestions.
I tried all the suggestions listed here. I am able to compile but at run time it fails because my db does not have _-migrations table.
